# LXC containers on host's lan

Tags: lxc

My LXC containers usually work with a masqueraded bridge, on a private network.

This time I would like to put the containers on the host's LAN, but I can't get any results.
I use LXC 2.0.7-2+deb9u2 on debian, and I refer to this documentation : [LXC/SimpleBridge](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC/SimpleBridge).

cfrbr0 is the bridge on the host, its IP is 192.168.0.12/24, it contains the physical interface (up with no IP) and lxc-net service is down.

```
[config]
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.name = eth0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = auto
lxc.network.link = cfrbr0
lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.0.13/24

[lxc-usernet]
test veth cfrbr0 100

$ sudo service lxc-net stop
$ lxc-start -n test-ct
$ lxc-attach -n test-ct -- sudo -i
# ip a
24: eth0@if25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9e:82:4f:5a:6c:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.13/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
# ip r
default via 192.168.0.12 dev eth0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.13
# ping 192.168.0.12
PING 192.168.0.12 (192.168.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
```

But :

```
# ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.0.254)
```

The host pings 1.1.1.1 and the veth is added to the bridge. IP forwarding is set to 1 on the host.
FYI, the host is a virtualbox VM on a macos (same issue on debian stretch virtualbox).

I think I'm misconfiguring the host-shared bridge because I don't have problem with a masqueraded bridge and a LXC private network. As a workaround, is there a possibility to put the containers into the local network with a masqueraded bridge ?

Thank you for your suggestions !

Answer (score 1):

When using VirtualBox on a Mac (over WiFi?) this requires a different approach because of how WiFi bridging works (https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/network_bridged.html).

The key in this setup is *not* to bridge `eth0` and don't use `lxc-net`.  On the host, /etc/network/interfaces is standard:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.8
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
```

A bridge is not needed (no `lxc-net`) but set the container config to create a virtual interface thusly:

```
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.veth.pair = veth0
lxc.net.0.flags = up
lxc.net.0.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:xx:xx:xx
lxc.net.0.ipv4.address = 192.168.0.64/32
lxc.net.0.ipv4.gateway = 192.168.0.8
lxc.net.0.script.up = /var/lib/lxc/netup.sh 192.168.0.64
lxc.net.0.script.down = /var/lib/lxc/netdown.sh 192.168.0.64
```

Some notes on this config: (1) there is no `lxc.net.0.link` since we don't want a bridge, (2) the `lxc.net.0.ipv4.gateway` address is the host's IP address, (3) note the netmask is `/32`, (4) the scripts are explained below.

The `netup.sh` script routes incoming IP traffic to the container and creates an ARP entry so that `eth0` will accept traffic for it:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip route add ${1}/32 dev veth0
arp -i eth0 -Ds ${1} eth0 pub
```

The `netdown.sh` script simply removes the ARP entry (the IP route will go away automatically when `veth0` is destroyed).

```
#!/bin/sh
arp -d -i eth0 ${1} pub
```

On the guest, /etc/network/interfaces can be empty, since in this case the setup was done in the container config file.

The end result on the host:

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  metric 202
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 192.168.0.8
192.168.0.64 dev veth0 scope link
# arp -a
...
? (192.168.0.64) at 00:16:3e:xx:xx:xx [ether]  on veth0
? (192.168.0.64) at * PERM PUP on eth0
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:192.168.0.8  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11476 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10425 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1253928 (1.1 MiB)  TX bytes:1328460 (1.2 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:112 (112.0 B)  TX bytes:112 (112.0 B)

veth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:9D:3D:14:4B:87
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1748 (1.7 KiB)  TX bytes:1748 (1.7 KiB)
```

And in the container:

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.0.8 dev eth0
192.168.0.8 dev eth0 scope link
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3E:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:192.168.0.64  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:23322 (22.7 KiB)  TX bytes:23322 (22.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

# ping -c 3 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=0 ttl=58 time=43.458 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=1 ttl=58 time=41.121 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=2 ttl=58 time=40.891 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 40.891/41.823/43.458 ms
```

I know this was stated in the question, but for anyone starting from scratch, make sure forwarding is enabled, `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward ; echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`.

My other answer works for KVM and might be useful for others so I won't edit it, but this one is more specific to VirtualBox and WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

What about sharing the network namespace of the host with the container ? To make it, you can use the *--share-net* option of *lxc-start* command to which you pass the pid of a process running on host side (e.g. pid#1). Then, the container will be in the network namespace as the host and so, will see all the available network interfaces of the host.

```
lxc-start -n container_name --share-net 1
```

Comment: With non-privileged containers, I try with the bash PID, but I got the following error: "Failed to attach net namespace". However, If I understand correctly, share-net shares a network space ignoring the specific network configuration of the container. What is then the IP of the container?

Comment: As the container sees the same interfaces as the host, it has the same IP. In those conditions, the IP ports are used to direct the traffic or the container application needs to configure one of the available interfaces. But with unprivileged containers, this perhaps impossible to do...

Comment: Ok... it can't be my solution... but thank you for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing this exact problem, the key for me was to manually set the `src` in the container's default route.

On the host, /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.zz
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway xx.xx.xx.1
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

(note there is no entry for `eth0` and `xx.xx.xx.zz` is the primary/main public IP of the host)

On the host, the network part of /var/lib/lxc/[container]/config:

```
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.link = br0
lxc.net.0.flags = up
lxc.net.0.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:xx:xx:xx
```

On the container, /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.yy
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        post-up ip route add default via xx.xx.xx.1 src xx.xx.xx.yy
hostname $(hostname)
```

Note the `src xx.xx.xx.yy` where the IP address is the external IP being assigned to the container.

The result of this on the container:

```
# ip route
default via xx.xx.xx.1 dev eth0  src xx.xx.xx.yy
xx.xx.xx.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src xx.xx.xx.yy
# ping -c 3 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=0 ttl=58 time=12.499 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=1 ttl=58 time=19.876 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=2 ttl=58 time=12.894 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 12.499/15.089/19.876 ms
```

And on the host:

```
# ip route
default via xx.xx.xx.1 dev br0
xx.xx.xx.0/24 dev br0 scope link  src xx.xx.xx.zz
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.00163c024f42       no              eth0
                                                        vethBEQF56
# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3C:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:xx.xx.xx.zz  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:85102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3682 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4238847 (4.0 MiB)  TX bytes:570002 (556.6 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3C:xx:xx:xx
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:92881 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6038953 (5.7 MiB)  TX bytes:588494 (574.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:66440 (64.8 KiB)  TX bytes:66440 (64.8 KiB)

vethBEQF56 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:C8:14:A3:16:48
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26610 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6602 (6.4 KiB)  TX bytes:1610963 (1.5 MiB)
```

Comment: I read over the bit about you using VirtualBox on a Mac - probably over WiFi?  This needs a bit of a different answer, I'll write it separately.